# How to execute a SQL statement?

Tags: java, select

`error: java.lang.NullPointerException`     ,  What is the reason??

My class name is ; `DP.java`

```
public static TPreparedStatement Fill(SessionStruct ss, 
        String seq) throws SQLException {
    TPreparedStatement tp = null;

    try {

        String sql = "Select name,surname from NAMES where seq=? ";

        tp = new TPreparedStatement(ss, sql);
        tp.setString(1, seq);
        tp.executeQuery();
        tp.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        tp.close();
        ss.rollbackNoException();
        ex.printStackTrace();
        throw ex;
    }
    return tp;

}
```

Another class is ; `DLP.java`

```
public void Load() throws HException {
    TPreparedStatement tp = null;
    try {
        tp = DP.Fill(rc.ss, rc.getRequest()
                .getParameter("PK"));

        txtName.setValue(tp.getString("NAME"));    
        txtSurname.setValue(tp.getString("SURNAME"));

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        rc.ss.rollbackNoException();
    }
}
```

When I run in debug mode it has skipped ;

```
txtName.setValue(tp.getString("NAME"));    
txtSurname.setValue(tp.getString("SURNAME"));
```

Comment: This is not a pl-sql program.

Comment: I think that nullpointer exception came with a line number on which it occurred?  Knowing on what line the NPE occurred would help us help you.

Comment: Is this WSO2's TPreparedStatement?  If so, you're not using it correctly - executeQuery returns a ResultSet.  Time to dig up the documentation I think...

Comment: Before tp.close(); check if tp is not null: if(tp != null) tp.close();

Answer (score 1):

Just a wild guess as we obviously lack of some informations here. Anyway:

You conscientiously closed your `TPreparedStatment`  before returning from `Fill`. Then, in the caller, you invoke methods on that closed statement:

```
public static TPreparedStatement Fill(SessionStruct ss, 
        String seq) throws SQLException {
    TPreparedStatement tp = null;

    try {
        ...
        tp.close();    // <--------------
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        tp.close();    // <--------------
        ...
    }
    return tp;
}
```

```
    tp = DP.Fill(rc.ss, rc.getRequest()
            .getParameter("PK"));

    txtName.setValue(tp.getString("NAME")); 
    //               ^^
    //            closed !
```

I can't guarantee *this* cause your `NullPointerException`. But it is usually not advisable to call any method on a closed object, as according to the [usual semantic](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AutoCloseable.html), calling `close` on an object should relinquishing any underlying resources.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a finally block for closing your tp resource.
Also could be helpful to see the full stacktrace to investigate the null pointer.

```
try {
    String sql = "Select name,surname from NAMES where seq=? ";

    tp = new TPreparedStatement(ss, sql);
    tp.setString(1, seq);
    tp.executeQuery();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    ss.rollbackNoException();
    ex.printStackTrace();
    throw ex;
} finally {
    tp.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all ..

Right I forgat  -->  tp.close(); statement like this;

try {
        ...
        tp.close();    // <--------------
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        tp.close();    // <--------------
        ...
    }
    return tp;